# linux "date" is correct but python tzlocal reports utc in docker container

Tags: django, docker

I am mounting in the docker compose file

```
volumes:
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

When I go into the container with 
`docker exec -it <containername> bash`
then run `date` it shows up properly.  But in django and in python3 editor tzlocal shows UTC.

`ogixbuild$ docker exec -it qlogixwebapi bash
root@3e1a15562c2f:/var/lib/django/webapi# date
Thu Feb  8 15:14:31 MST 2018
root@3e1a15562c2f:/var/lib/django/webapi# python3
Python 3.6.4 (default, Dec 21 2017, 01:35:12) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 import tzlocal
 tzlocal.get_localzone()
<StaticTzInfo 'Etc/UTC'>`

Anyone have any experience with this know how to get tzlocal to get the correct timezone?

Comment: Is this django python shell? then following is relevant https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone

Comment: No, this is a bash shell in the docker container. I see that on my host machine /etc/localtime is a symlink and in the docker container /etc/localtime is a file (the result of the host symlink)  I am thinking this has something to do with it.

Comment: try `env | grep TZ`

Comment: That returns nothing.  I see now in the tzlocal source that it tries to get the timezone from the environment first, then it looks in /etc/timezone.  My /etc/timezone contains Etc/UTC.  So it is not even getting to the code in tzlocal that looks at /etc/localtime.  So I need my docker compose or Dockerfile to populate the /etc/timezone or set the TZ environment variable.

Comment: true, that is why I wanted to see the result. however, in redhat, the resolve path was `/etc/localtime` which is a symlink to one of the files in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. Not sure about `/etc/timezone`

Comment: I have the /etc/localtime/ symlink as well but tzlocal checks that later.  Because it finds a value in /etc/timezone it uses that. I think with my script I may be able to generate a file with the tz info, copy it into the container, then in the entrypoint.sh script copy the timezone into /etc/timezone.  It needs to be dynamic so I cannot hardcode it in the dockerfile.  Freaking docker should have an easy button for using host timezone

Comment: Let's know what worked for you, if you managed to solve it. I was wondering about /etc/timezone because that is not mentioned in the man page for date but /etc/localtime is.

Comment: What OS are you on and is your docker container on ? I think /etc/timezone file is the debian/ubuntu way and /etc/localtime symlink is the CentOS/Redhat way BUT YMMV in fact some applications running on ubuntu look for /etc/localtime and some applications running anywhere ignore the timezone set in OS and use their own start up arguments to set timezone.

Answer (score 1):

So by adding both volumes to the docker-compose file I now have working timezones.  Both the `date` command and tzlocal work.

```
volumes:
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
```

> root@96245334a7c9:/var/lib/django/webapi# date
>
> Thu Feb  8 18:45:23 MST 2018
>
> root@96245334a7c9:/var/lib/django/webapi# python3
>
> Python 3.6.4 (default, Dec 21 2017, 01:35:12)
>
> [GCC 4.9.2] on linux
>
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> import tzlocal
>
> tzlocal.get_localzone()
>
> DstTzInfo 'America/Denver' LMT-1 day, 17:00:00 STD

As you can see both `date` and tzlocal now return the correct time with timezone.  Now my django apps work as expected.

I like this approach because it gets the hosts time into the docker container dynamically.  No hardcoded timezones or anything.